# Присваивание переменной Java метода

Tags: android

Объясните ситуацию, когда переменной в качестве значения присваивается метод.
Например, при работе с фрагментами пишем следующее:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
```

Я не совсем понимаю, как переменной fm типа FragmentManager присваивается метод. Что хранит в себе дальше эта переменная, ссылку на метод или какое-то значение? Пытался проделать такой трюк с любым методом моего класса, не получается.

Comment: переменной присваивается то, что находится после оператора `return` в таком методе (то есть значение), а не сам метод.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Переменной не присваивается метод. Ей присваивается объект, являющийся возвращаемым значением метода. Т.е. метод выглядит как-то так:

```
public FragmentManager getFragmentManager() {
    return new FragmentManager();
}
```

В итоге при вызове метода создаётся объект `FragmentManager` и, если перед вызовом метода находится переменная слева от `=`, то этой переменной присваивается этот объект в качестве значения.

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь понял.